# Как пронумеровать класс элементов списка

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

Как добавить пронумерованный класс с привязкой к событию(клику). Цель заключается в том, чтоб при клике на кнопку, добавлялся элемент (ul > li) и ему присваивался класс с его номером, например 'item-' + i. Еще нужно учесть, что элементы добавляются в localStorage.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('todo-list');
const input = document.getElementById('input-text');
const btn = document.getElementById('button-add');


btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if (input.value == '') {
    alert("input text");
  }

  let itemID;
  // При каждом клике значение i обнуляется, в итоге на выходе получется один и тот же класс
  let i = 0;

  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = input.value;

  do {
    i++;
    itemID = 'item-' + i;
  } while (i < localStorage.length);

  li.className = itemID;


  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  deleteButton.className = 'btn-delete';
  deleteButton.innerText = 'x';

  list.appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(deleteButton);

  input.value = '';
  const saveList = list.innerHTML;
  localStorage.setItem('saveList', saveList);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>To do list</h1>

    <form id="todo-form" class="form" method="post">
      <input id="input-text" type="text" name="text" placeholder="input text">
      <button id="button-add" type="button" name="button">Get</button>
    </form>

    <ol id="todo-list"></ol>
  </div>
```

Comment: сейчас никакой класс не присваивается?
вынесите i за пределы функции

Comment: мне нужно область видимости подробнее изучить, второй раз с этим сталкиваюсь)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как-то так:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.form-btn');
var text = document.querySelector('.form-text');
var list = document.querySelector('.list');
var listNum = 0;
var myStorage = localStorage;

btn.onclick = function() {
  if (!text.value == "") {
    list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML + "<li class=\"list-item" + listNum + "\">" + text.value + "</li>";

    myStorage.setItem('saveList', list.innerHTML);

    text.value = "";
    listNum++;
  } else alert("Empty field");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-text">
<button class="form-btn">Добавить</button>


<ul class="list"></ul>
```

[Код](https://jsfiddle.net/daniel217/m5sfot1j/) на JSFiddle